# Pandas Comparing Two Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.  I will explain my requirement in form of a loop--because this is how I visualize the problem.
I realize that there can be another solution, so if this can be done differently, please feel free to share!  I am new to Pandas, so I'm struggling with this solution.  Thank you in advance for looking at my question!!

I have 2 dataframes that have 3 columns:  ID, ODO, ODOLength.  ODOLength is the running difference for each ODO record, which I got using: `abs(Df1['Odo'] - Df1['Odo'].shift(-1))`

```
OldDataSet = {'id' : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140],'Odo': [-1.09,1.02,26.12,43.12,46.81,56.23,111.07,166.38,191.27,196.41,207.74,231.61,235.84,240.04], 'OdoLength':[2.11,25.1,17,3.69,9.42,54.84,55.31,24.89,5.14,11.33,23.87,4.23,4.2,4.09]}

NewDataSet = {'id' : [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000],'Odo': [1.51,2.68,4.72,25.03,42,45.74,55.15,110.05,165.41,170.48,172.39,190.35,195.44,206.78], 'OdoLength':[1.17,2.04,20.31,16.97,3.74,9.41,54.9,55.36,5.07,1.91,17.96,5.09,11.34,23.89]}

FinalResultDataSet = {'DFOneId':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110], 'DFTwoID' : [1000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,11000,12000,13000,14000], 'OdoDiff': [2.6,3.7,1.09,1.12,1.07,1.08,1.02,6.01,0.92,0.97,0.96], 'OdoLengthDiff':[0.94,4.79,0.03,0.05,0.01,0.06,0.05,6.93,0.05,0.01,0.02], 'OdoAndLengthDiff':[1.66,1.09,1.06,1.07,1.06,1.02,0.97,0.92,0.87,0.96,0.94]}


df1= pd.DataFrame(OldDataSet)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(NewDataSet)

FinalDf = pd.DataFrame(FinalResultDataSet)
```

The logic behind how to get the FinalDF is as follows: Take Odo and OdoLen from df1 and subtract it from each Odo and OdoLen columns in df2.  Take the lowest value of the difference and match them.  For next comparison of Df1 and Df2, begin with the first Df2 record that does not have a match.  If Df2 values are not a minimum value, for the current Df1 values
that is being compared then that record of DF2 is not included in the final dataset.  For example, Df1 ID 20- was compared to Df2 ID 2000 and the final result was 21.4 ((DfOne.ODO:1.02-DfTwo.ODO:2.68) - (DfOneODOLen:25.1-DfTwo.ODoLen-2.04) = 21.4), however when Df1 ID 20 is compared to Df2 3000 the final difference is 1.09 ((DfOne.ODO:1.02-DfTwo.ODO:4.72) - (DfOneODOLen:25.1-DfTwo.ODoLen-20.31) = 1.06).  In this case, Df2 ID 3000 is matched to DF1 ID 20 and Df2 ID - 2000 is dropped off because
the difference was larger.  At this point DF2 ID 2000 is not considered for any other matches.  So the next DF1 record comparison would start at DF2 ID 4000, because that is the next value that does not have a match.

As I said, I am open to all suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `merge_asof`

Step 1: combine the dataframe

```
df1['match']=df1.Odo+df1.OdoLength
df2['match']=df2.Odo+df2.OdoLength

out=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='match',direction='nearest')
out.drop_duplicates(['id_y'])
Out[728]:
     Odo_x  OdoLength_x  id_x   match   Odo_y  OdoLength_y   id_y
0    -1.09         2.11    10    1.02    1.51         1.17   1000
1     1.02        25.10    20   26.12    4.72        20.31   3000
2    26.12        17.00    30   43.12   25.03        16.97   4000
3    43.12         3.69    40   46.81   42.00         3.74   5000
4    46.81         9.42    50   56.23   45.74         9.41   6000
5    56.23        54.84    60  111.07   55.15        54.90   7000
6   111.07        55.31    70  166.38  110.05        55.36   8000
7   166.38        24.89    80  191.27  172.39        17.96  11000
8   191.27         5.14    90  196.41  190.35         5.09  12000
9   196.41        11.33   100  207.74  195.44        11.34  13000
10  207.74        23.87   110  231.61  206.78        23.89  14000
```

Step 2

Then you can do something like below to get your new column

```
out['OdoAndLengthDiff']=out.OdoLength_x-out.OdoLength_y+out.Odo_x-out.Odo_y
```

***BTW*** I did not drop the column , after you get all new value if you need, You can drop it by using `out=out.drop([columns],1)`

Comment: Wow.... this is awesome.   this is exactly what I am looking for.  I am stunned at how little lines of code this is.  In Sql Server this would be a nightmare!!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: wow so surprised by the code that I forgot the important part!  :-)

Comment: i am trying this with a larger data set.  In this case, df1 is actually shorter than df2 list.  Any idea why  I get this error?
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1243, in _get_join_indexers
    raise ValueError('left' + msg)

ValueError: left keys must be sorted

Comment: sort the match , before it , using `df=df.sort_values('match')`

Comment: i tried sorting both df first, and then doing the merge, but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @yanci after you create the column `match`, you sort the `match` and do not forgot assign it back

Comment: it was complaining because the result set had null values.  So I had to remove the nulls from both datasets and then it worked!

Comment: @yanci yeah using `dropna()`

Comment: which one is better, df1 = df1[df1['match'].notnull()] or dropna()?

Comment: @yanci I would say dropna () since it is develop for this case .. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html